# Moved UINavigationBar redraws in wrong location after app becomes active from background

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have a `UINavigationBar` which is moved upwards (including off-screen) when the scroll view below it scrolls up. When (after pressing the Home Button) the app becomes inactive and is then resumed, the display comes back as it was beforehand, but the navigation bar is redrawn at the default position (below the status bar). When I tap the screen and scroll a minimal amount it jumps into place where it should be (usually off-screen in that case).

Is there anything short of full-blown app-restoration that can be done to rectify this?

The `UINavigationBar` is shifted by setting its frame. After the app becomes active, I make sure the frame is re-set to the correct size, but it still draws in the 'standard' place.

Needless to say I have already tried a multitude of approaches & forced re-draws, but to no avail. Hiding and then showing it again, calling `setNeedsDisplay` etc.

(This is on iOS 7)

Comment: As a working solution I have now set up a Notification when the app becomes active again. This triggers setting the scroll view's content offset to the initial value, so that the navigation bar then is in the right position. Losing the exact scrolling point in the view is less severe than having a messed up display. Not ideal, but an acceptable trade-off.